# Открытие файла .py через pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Пользуюсь pycharm уже сколько времени, а так и не научился открывать файл НОРМАЛЬНО. Дело всё в том, что во многих гайдах люди, пользующиеся другими редкаторами, спокойно открывают .py файлы в обычном их представлении: Консоль и/или графический интерфейс программы. Но у меня всё по другому, когда я нажимаю на этот файлик, оно открывается в редакторе Pycharm, а не запускается. Что делать? Подскажите

Comment: а где в свойствах "открыть с помощью"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правой кнопкой на файле - Свойства - Открыть с помощью - выбрать интерпретатор питона.

Comment: Да, но это одноразовый способ, он не будет открываться так всегда. Но возможно ли как-то указать, как будет открываться файл в файле .bat?

Comment: a) если заметить галочку "всегда так открывать такой тип файлов" и поставить ее, то будет. б) вопрос про .bat непонятен